# "we women", "you women", "they women", "we men", "you men", "they men"

Tags: subjects

> ''A woman from the government said, '*We women* are walking with our heads up, and *you men* will have to put your tails down,' '' Loroupe recalled. (The New York Times)

I know that one subject is enough, but supposing that due to  some idiomatic reasons "we women" and "you men" are correct—are they?—, can we infer that each pronoun can be used the same way—i.e., "I woman", "they men" and so on?

For example, can the following sentence be legally pronunced by a woman who is speaking to another woman?

> *We women* know things that *they men* will never  understand.

Answer (score 11):

No, you really can't infer that.

The *we* and *you* in *we women* and *you men* are correct; they are [determiners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners), serving to specify WHICH women and men the speaker is talking about.

In this case, the speaker could have said simply "Women are walking with their heads up, men will have to put their tails down", but using the determiners adds some punch and directness to her address and makes it clear that the speaker is part of the "women" group and the people she is addressing are part of the "men" group.

There are other places where determiners are appropriate, but that does not include going with a singular pronoun, since there is no need to further clarify which individual you are talking about.

In the specific example you give ("we women know things they men will never understand"), *they* is not really functional as a determiner; you would either leave the pronoun out entirely: `we women know things that men will never understand` if you mean "all men", or you would say `we women know things that those men will never understand` if you're talking about a particular group of men.

Comment: Excellent! I never thought of this, but as soon as I read it it Click!ed.

Comment: In casual/informal speech, many people would say *"**Us** women know things **them** men will never understand"*, though probably most would feel it's at least an "uneducated" usage. I don't think you can explain it away with "rules" though - those who naturally say *us* won't have a problem using *them* in the same way, but those who say *we* don't really have a precise equivalent in this context. It's just established idiomatic usages, I think.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Interestingly according to Google NGram, "We women" is consistently more popular than "Us women" (which is also widely used), but "Us men" and "We men" are equivilently common: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=us+men%2Cwe+men%2Cus+women%2C+we+women&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Using _us_ and _them_ in that context is perhaps best regarded as nonstandard. _We women_ would be standard, and any speaker who used that would almost certainly follow it with _those men_, although that loses the symmetry of the nonstandard construction. I have said in my own answer that _they men_ would be grammatical, but would probably be avoided for the reason I give.

Comment: I'm not sure about the analysis of the pronoun as a determiner - isn't it more logical to regard the second noun phrase ("women", etc.) as an [apposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) here?  Isn't this basically the same construct as in "Charles Darwin, the well-known naturalist, (...)" or "Mr. Smith, four times winner of the (whatever) Contest, (...)" ?

Comment: @reinierpost. I agree, more or less, as I've shown in my answer. _We_ and _you_ are certainly not determiners.

Comment: @Barrie: On reconsidering, I think you're right - the "asymettry" of *us/them* not really being matched by *we/they* is just an illusion. Even those who naturally use *us* and *them* in such contexts wouldn't normally use both in a single utterance unless they meant *those men* (or *these men*). it just so happens that both *us* and *we* can be used to mean either *us/we **specific** group of women*, or *us/we **representing women in general***. But for the counterpart, no speaker really has a single word covering both those meanings (a *specific group*, or *all* men).

Answer (score 3):

> We women know things that **they men** will never understand.

isn't quite right. *they* is a pronoun referring to *men*. You would have to say

> We women know things that **they** will never understand.

or

> We women know things that **those men** will never understand.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to use a determiner with a singular personal pronoun such as *I*, *you(s)*, or *he/she/it* although it *is* grammatical to use a noun phrase in apposition that has a similar effect (although it sounds somewhat old fashioned):

> I, the rightful heir to the throne, will retake my kingdom!
>
> You, the son of a billionaire, could never understand the plight of the poor.

Normally a native English speaker would prefer a more idiomatic expression such as the following:

> As the rightful heir to the throne, I will retake my kingdom!
>
> As the son of a billionaire, you could never understand the plight of the poor.

**They men** is also ungrammatical. You can use **those men**, **these men** or just **men**, or possibly a creatively defined subset of men using **men who <expr>**:

> We women have just as much right to vote as **men**.
>
> We women have just as much right to vote as **those men**.
>
> We women have just as much right to vote as **men who would prefer it if we stayed at home**.

Comment: Mmm ... in your first two examples those sound to me like personal pronouns followed by noun phrases in apposition rather than determiners followed by the noun phrases they govern.

Comment: I agree with this, but it doesn't really answer the question: it doesn't explain why "We women" is more acceptable than "They men". Perhaps this construct has partially leaked over from German? In German, "Wir Frauen",  "Du Feigling" etc. are perfectly normal.

Comment: @reinierpost: The reasons **why** the language has got like this is an etymology question, not a English learning one. For English learners the simple rule is that it is not allowed. If you want a more in depth answer, try ELU.SE.

Answer (score 2):

In *we women* and *you men*, *we* and *you* remain pronouns. They are not determiners. *Women* and *men*, in the words of the ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’, simply ‘make the reference more explicit’. The Longman Grammar’s own examples are *We all* and *We Americans*.

On those grounds, *We women know things that they men will never understand* is grammatical, but is probably best avoided because of the risk that *they men* will be taken as a solecism in place of *those*.